# InDesign: auto resize of table cells

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting

Is there a way to fit table cells to their content? (InDesign)

Comment: You could set table height to a very low value and set it as the lowest value instead of strict. This automatically changes the table cells' height to its content.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set all cells to "At least" and do width and height size as 1mm.

From personal experience I would advise against it as you could end with cell in the middle of a table with a lot of text. So the middle Column and Row would be large while other ones could be very thin.